# ApplicationWorkingSetLimit returns 0 in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a **Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1** app that has been using `ApplicationWorkingSetLimit` to detect high- and low-memory devices. However on 8.1 I found out that this value returns 0, not the app limit.

```
long result = (long)DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationWorkingSetLimit");
return result <= 188743680; // 188743680 (180mb) is the maximum a low mem device
```

Because the result is always 0, it is flagging even high-end devices as low memory. I've tried this on the 8.1 emulators and my Lumia 920 with no difference. I have no effective way to tell what is high or low anymore. Is this a bug in the OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Windows.System.MemoryManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.memorymanager.aspx)'s [`AppMemoryUsageLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.memorymanager.appmemoryusagelimit.aspx) property.

```
var limit = Windows.System.MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit;
// some limit comparison here
```

And here are the memory caps for different devices:

[image: Memory caps for WP 8.1 apps]

Comment: thanks, for the record, the limits are exact, so 185MB means exactly 185 * 1024 * 1024 bytes

Answer (score 0):

2 things to try:

1. Change 188743680 to 188743680L. It probably doesn't matter, but best to be sure.
2. Try enabling the `ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE` capability. The documentation says that you don't need it, but maybe that's having an affect.

Comment: My code is the exact same as yours (except I use the `L` suffix) and it works perfectly on emulators and devices. Where exactly are you making the call?

Comment: Actually, my project is for WPS 8.0, not 8.1. Maybe that's making a difference?

Comment: yes, I figure that must be the reason. The officially stated way from Microsoft to detect a low mem device does not seem to work for windows phone silverlight 8.1

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. If you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642084(v=vs.105).aspx search for the section title **Use Windows.System.MemoryManager to determine your app’s memory usage** it will tell you to use @yasen's solution.

Comment: Good to hear. Can you please mark @yasen's answer as correct to help others?